# Add where clause if not NULL

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

here is my query:

```
    List<string> kwList = GetFilterKeywords(); // returns NULL none keyword selected
    var res = from d in ctx.Books
    where (kwList == null || kwList.Contains(d.Name))
    select d;
```

Looks like it is not legit to add where clause if kwList is NULL. So my question is: Is there any way to add more where clauses to the same query in IF/ELSE IF construction?

I mean:

```
    var res = from d in ctx.Books
              select d;
    if (kwList != null)
    {
       res.Where(d => kwList.Contains(d.Name);
    }
```

Comment: *Either* you're using Linq-to-SQL (the ORM built by the C# team as a *proof-of-concept* for LINQ - uses `DataContext` class and `.dbml` model file), ***OR*** you're using Entity Framework (possibly with a `.edmx` model file, or a code-first approach), and then you're using Linq-to-Entities queries - but you cannot use both at the same time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var res = ctx.Books; // no need to write select
if (kwList != null)
    res = res.Where(x => kwList.Contains(x.Name));

foreach (d in res) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tertiary operator

```cs
var res = kwList == null ? ctx.Books : ctx.Books.Where(x => kwList.Contains(x.Name));
```

If you want to modify the initial linq query in subsequent case statements, make sure to reassign the initial query to the modified:

```cs
    var res = ctx.Books;
    if (a == b) 
    {
        // reassign here
        res = res.Where(x => kwList.Contains(x.Name));
    } 
    else if (a == c) 
       res = res.Where(x => x.Id == y);
```

Comment: Also, it is best to be explicit on the type of res (IQueryable<T> not var) to avoid trying to dynamically add a .Where clause after a .OrderBy.